# How do you execute several bash functions in the background but wait for output?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I am trying to make a bash function to execute several web scrapes (using curl and such), and I want to have them all execute concurrently in the background, and all print their output to stdin.  How is this possible?

Comment: Print to stdout, surely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an easy one! You can use `&` for this even for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

x() { echo =$1=Solaris; sleep 1; echo =$1=East; sleep 1; echo =$1=Panta Rhei;}

x one&
x two&

echo Syrius; sleep 1
echo After Crying
```

Output:

```
=one=Solaris
Syrius
=two=Solaris
=one=East
=two=East
After Crying

Press ENTER or type command to continue
=one=Panta Rhei
=two=Panta Rhei
```

So `x` is running in the background and prints to `stdout`. The `Press ENTER or type command to continue` was presented by [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) (as I started the script from [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)) and shows that the background `x` process finishes its job after the main script finished. If You want to wait until all the background processes finish You can use the `$!` to get the PID of the background processes and the built-in `wait <PID>` as a last function.

Comment: I was originally doing something like that, but I couldn't figure out how to suppress the output from bash job control (`echo one & echo two & echo three` outputs: `[1] 27926 \ [2] 27927 \ three / one \ two \ [1]-  Done  echo one \ [2]+  Done  echo two`)

Comment: @Kevin: this was not in your Q. :) but actually starting functions in the bacground did not show the job information. I tested in [tag:cygwin], but I'll check it under [tag:linux] as well.

Comment: @Kevin: If you run it from the command prompt then the job info is written to the console. But if You run it from a script it is not written. Neither in `cygwin` nor in `linux˙.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes along:

Given the following:

```
function par() {
    parallel sh -c ::: "sleep 1" "sleep 1" "sleep 1"
}

function seq() {
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
}
```

Timing both commands shows that the first function executes all at once while the second function waits for each command to be finished before moving on to the next:

```
$ time par && time seq

real    0m1.215s
user    0m0.147s
sys     0m0.085s

real    0m3.028s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Happiness!

Comment: `parallel` is not installed on all Linux distributions. I usually use `make` if I have controlled run of parallel processes. With the option `-j` the max number of processes can be defined and with the option `-l` the max load can be set. See a detailed description in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565353/have-5-scripts-running-at-any-given-time/17566149#17566149)